# Одушевленность-неодушевленность

Tags: существительные, одушевленность

Станет ли неодушевленным существительное "рыба", перешедшее из категории живых существ в категорию, например, еды?

Comment: Нужен пример, и прописная будет не лишней.

Comment: @shampar Переходит разве "рыба", а не "существительное"? Как-то здесь ни то ни другое не звучит.

Comment: Было «перешедшие»... Вы у сами определитесь слово в категорию, или живая рыба в неживую. Проще будет  переформулировать.

Answer (score 2):

Рыба ― сущ. ж.р. ед. числа и не выражают категорию одушевленности-неодушевленности, но можно взять сочетание "три рыбки", где сущ. в форме мн. числа может быть одушевленным или неодушевленным.

В этом случае мы обычно говорим: **поймал трех рыбок (одуш.) и съел три рыбки (неод.)** Однако в этой теме может наблюдаться колебание форм.

Розенталь

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_08)

2. В различии форм поймал трех рыбок – съел три рыбки сказывается то обстоятельство, что во втором случае имеется в виду кушанье, т.е. неодушевленность (ср.: съесть кильки, сардины, шпроты – как нерасчлененный продукт; но: съесть карасей, раков, цыплят – как единичные предметы). Возможные варианты: есть креветок, устриц, пулярок – есть креветки, устрицы, пулярки. Такие же колебания наблюдаются у существительных матрешка, кукла, марионетка.